# Maintaining session with cookies android

Tags: android, session-cookies, setcookie

Hi I am developing android application in which i wanted to set cookies for session handling.
I am using datadroid library for network call which uses `HttpURLConnection` in background. After log in process I tried to set cookies and after that for every call i tried to pass cookies. But it gives me no valid session. I did this in following ways.
after login process :

```
header = result.headerMap //this gves me header part after log in responce.
```

so this header variable looks like

```
{Cache-Control=[no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0], 
***Connection=[close]***, Content-Encoding=[gzip], Content-Length=[173], Content-Location=
[login.php], Content-Type=[application/json], Date=[Wed, 20 Mar 2013 04:05:38 GMT], 
Expires=[Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT], Pragma=[no-cache], Server=[Apache/2.2.22 
(Fedora)],
 ***Set-Cookie***=[QCSESSID=mckdk1povn625jk1bhs11m0t97; path=/, 
QCSESSID=d44cnlf6gv2ii8lt76tr7vbqm4; path=/], TCN=[choice], Vary=[negotiate,Accept-
Encoding,User-Agent]}
```

SO for my next web call i using `Set-Cookies part`

```
    connect_status= header.get("Connection");
    login_cookie= header.get("Set-Cookie");
    cookie1=login_cookie.get(0);
    cookie2=login_cookie.get(1);

// This is datadroid syntax. So here I m setting cookies for my next call
 login_header.put("User-Agent"," Apache-HttpClient/4.2.3 (java 1.5)");
   login_header.put("Connection" ,"Keep-Alive");
   login_header.put("Cookie", cookie2);

   networkConnection.setHeaderList(login_header);
```

But still it gives me error that no valid session exits. My header response showing me that parameter for connection is closed so i tried with connection "keep-alive as well" But that also not working. Am I doing something wrong? Need help. How to solve this problem.

If I tried it with one of my GET API call its working fine. But when i use it with my PUT API call it gives me session problem "Session does not exit".

Thank you.

Comment: I am using put request